# .htaccess ignore directory

Tags: .htaccess

I've got a modx website using seo urls. Works like a charm.

Now i want an existing file in an existing directory to correctly display aswel, but am receiving the default modx 404 page instead.

modx, the website itself is located in the webroot and uses the following .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^.*internal\ dummy\ connection.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [F,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^foo\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.foo.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]

# Exclude /assets and /manager directories and images from rewrite rules
RewriteRule ^(manager|assets|update)/*$ - [L]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The update directory is where my existing file resides www.foo.com/update/index.html

In the update directory i use the following:

```
RewriteEngine Off

<IfModule mod_security.c>
# Turn the filtering engine Off
SecFilterEngine Off
</IfModule>

AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/domains/foo.com/.htpasswd/public_html/update/.htpasswd
AuthName "login"
require valid-user
```

As you can see this subdirectory is also password protected. But i doubt that is relative to my problem. In fact i've tinkered about with it... but so far no success.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
RewriteRule ^(manager|assets|update)/*$ - [L]
```

should be

```
RewriteRule ^(manager|assets|update)/.*$ - [L]
```

or just

```
RewriteRule ^(manager|assets|update)/ - [L]
```

In your rule the `*` applies to the `/`, so it matches 'zero or more forward slashes'